# MySQL query not working properly. Select should return at least something?

Tags: mysql, select, replace

My table has one column containing string, email data, its name is email. My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM email 
WHERE LCASE(replace(replace(gmail, ' ', ''), '.', ''))='zarlengod@gmailcom'
```

In table there is email 'zarlengod@gmail.com', and after replacing '.', I should get 'zarlengod@gmailcom', and therefore select query should return some result, but it did not? I have to transform strings in that way.

Comment: You can test manually using a literal string to confirm that your comparison is correct: `select LCASE(replace(replace('zarlengod@gmail.com', ' ', ''), '.', ''))='zarlengod@gmailcom'` returns 1 (true). I would guess there's something in the string that still isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: the query won't return any rows if there aren't any rows that satisfy the predicate.

I suspect that there's some other unexpected character in the `gmail` column of this particular row that you're looking for. The expression in your query would "work" for `'zarlengod@gmail.com'`.

How do you know there's a row with that value? What does a query with this predicate return?

```
WHERE gmail = 'zarlengod@gmail.com'
```

If that doesn't return a row, then you could test for unexpected characters. Most likely would be at the end of the string. See if this returns the row:

```
WHERE gmail LIKE 'zarlengod@gmail.com%'
```

(In the LIKE predicate, the % character is a wildcard that matches zero one or more of any character.) Try matching smaller parts of the value:

```
WHERE gmail LIKE '%zarlengod%gmail%'
```

(If your column is defined with a case sensitive collation, you may need to use the `LOWER()` aka `LCASE()` function. But if it's case insensitive collation, you won't need to.)

If that returns a row, then you might want to use `HEX(gmail)`, `LENGTH(gmail)` to help diagnose the problem further.

Some common pesky characters are newline, carriage return, and tab:

```
REPLACE(  ,'\n','')
REPLACE(  ,'\r','')
REPLACE(  ,'\t','')
```

Another possibility that it's not really a period between gmail and com, but a comma instead. If you've got some other identifier you can use to return the row, the HEX() function can be a convenient way to "dump" the contents of a VARCHAR column for more careful examination of its contents.

Sometimes I find it convenient to do a comparison like this:

```
SELECT 't', LENGTH(gmail), HEX(gmail) FROM email WHERE id = 1234
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', LENGTH('zarlengod@gmail.com'), HEX('zarlengod@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Thank you, there was, indeed new line character at the end of email name